# Matlab: construction of very large sparse band matrix with as little memory and computation

Tags: performance, matlab, memory, vectorization, sparse-matrix

I need to construct a large NxN sparse band matrix A with N = 570*720 = 410400 (# of image pixels).

Mathematically, A(m,n) = C1 * exp(-|m-n|^2); m = 1:N, n = 1:N

Basically its a Gaussian function evaluated at each row with row index being the mean and some arbitrary but small standard deviation.

For N = 100, it looks like:[image: Gauss]

Unfortunately, it runs very slow for N = 410400 due to unnecessary computations.

1) using for loop

`A = sparse(N,N);

    for i=1:N

       A(i,:) = normpdf(1:N, i, 30);

    end`

This is wasteful and slow due to calling normpdf N times.

2) compute normpdf once for 1:2N with mean at N and then circularly shift the row in A with appropriate mean based on index. circshift in matlab can't shift a matrix column wise 
with different shift sizes. Again will need to call circshift N times --> wasteful.

3) use mvnpdf perhaps but it needs input vectors and generating these with meshgrids will
consume lot of memory.

4) use bsxfun with user defined gaussian function (with fixed SD) accepting two parameters as bsxfun does not take >3 arguments.

Any ideas on how this can achieved efficiently?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need the matrix? i.e., why not compute the value `A(i,j)` in-place where you need it?

Comment: @Rody The matrix is part of a larger optimization equation. explicitly computing A(i,j) N times esp when N is very large is wasteful don't you think? I am trying to vectorize and reduce loopy computations as much as possible.

Comment: You don't need to recompute values, you just compute the `normpdf` for a symmetric `2*Nx1` vector, and do smart indexing *into that vector* when you need some value. Seems a lot less wasteful than having an NxN matrix with only copies of the first and last row in it...

Comment: exactly! I need to construct such a matrix but I want to vectorize the indexing...I am investigating if bsxfun could be used for that purpose at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May I suggest another approach altogether.

What would be against using a `2*N-by-1` vector, that can be indexed with a simple transformation on the indices? Like so:

```
% Oli's solution, and your request: NxN matrix
N   = 100;
s   = 30;    
pdf = @(x) 1/(sqrt(2*pi)*s)*exp(-0.5*(bsxfun(@minus,x(:),1:N)/s).^2);
A   = pdf(1:N);

% My solution: 2*N x 1 vector
B = exp(-0.5*((-N:N)/s).^2) / s/sqrt(2*pi);
```

The trick is to find a nice general indexing rule. Here's how to do it:

```
% Indexing goes like this:
fromB = @(ii,jj) B(N+1 + bsxfun(@minus, jj(:), ii)).';

ii = 30; 
jj = 23;

from_A = A(ii,jj)
from_B = fromB(ii,jj)

ii = 1:2;    
jj = 4:6;      

from_A = A(ii, jj)
from_B = fromB(ii,jj)
```

Results:

```
from_A =
   0.012940955690785
from_B =
   0.012940955690785

from_A =
   0.013231751582567   0.013180394696194   0.013114657203398
   0.013268557543798   0.013231751582567   0.013180394696194
from_B =
   0.013231751582567   0.013180394696194   0.013114657203398
   0.013268557543798   0.013231751582567   0.013180394696194
```

I'm sure you can figure out how to do things like colon-indexing and using the `end` keyword :)

Comment: The `find(normpdf(1:N, 396, 50) < eps,1,'first')` shows how you can even calculate a much smaller B. But this is definitely the way to go, not `bsxfun()`.

Comment: @OlegKomarov: You shouldn't use `eps` there, but `realmin`. For the example you give, this gives `ans = 2272`. Smaller than the OP's `N`, but not *that* small :)

Comment: @Rody that does it. thanks :) Just discovered bsxfun...very handy!

Comment: @OlegKomarov: (`realmin == eps(0)`, which is the smallest `double`. The command `eps` by itself means `eps(1)`)

Comment: Definitely right with `eps(0)`. All in all, the point is that there is some threshold that makes the plot perceptually indifferent even from computing values to `eps(0)`, and computing **at most** as many values to `eps(0)` precision is the way to go for performance intensive applications.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you really do not need a sparse matrix unless you have at least 50% of zeros but your matrix is **full**.

Consider the pdf of a normal

[image]

You can easily implement it including a call to `bsxfun()`:

```
N   = 100;
s   = 30;
m   = 1:N;
pdf = @(x) 1/(sqrt(2*pi)*s)*exp(-0.5*(bsxfun(@minus,x(:),m)/s).^2);
B   = pdf(1:N);
```

A simple example with `mean = 1` and `sigma = 30` will clarify:

```
pdf = @(x) 1/(sqrt(2*pi)*30)*exp(-0.5*((x-1)/30).^2);
pdf(1)
ans =
        0.0132980760133811

normpdf(1, 1, 30)
ans =
        0.0132980760133811
```

Comment: Even 50% zeros is hardly worth the effort to create a sparse matrix. You won't gain anything by making such a matrix sparse.

Comment: @Oleg&wood no my matrix is extremely sparse depending on the standard deviation obviously. Consider: N = 720*570; A = sparse(N,N);  
A(1,:) = normpdf(1:N, 1, 50);
length(find(A(1,:)) = 1924;  size(A(1,:),2) = 410400

Comment: bsxfun() is nice soln. learning bsxfun at the moment but it will run of memory as it forms the intermediary vectors/matrices.

Comment: Your loop example is inconsistent with your previous comment. If for each row you are creating `1:N` draws from the normal, then it cannot be sparse. My approach simply reproduces your loop example, using less memory.

Comment: no each row is not drawing from a gaussian distribution but is a gaussian function centered at row index. if u see in the earlier code snippet, 1920/410400 columns for that row are non zero (or above the least double precision number)

Comment: Gaussian and normal are synonyms. Anyways, I start to understand what you're doing and the problem is that `find(normpdf(1:N, 396, 50) < eps,1,'first')` is 792, no matter how big `N` you only need to compute 792 values from the normal once, then spread it with sparse indexing. No bsxfun() needed at all. However, how many values are over the `eps`, depends on sigma.

Comment: yeah...regarding the Gaussian vs Normal thingy, in my head however normal somehow brings up pictures of a special case of Gaussian distribution with zero mean and unit variance. and so normal _ised_...nothing important, at times my fingers auto correct involuntarily